# Google Maps rendering Inverse of Counter-Clockwise Oriented Polygons

Tags: google-maps, polygon

I have found some cases where Google Maps renders the inverse of a polygon that I have defined. At first, I thought that it was related to polygons that stretch from -180 Longitude to +180 Longitude but I have repeated all these tests with (-179, +179) and found exactly the same behaviour.

Consider the following idealised polygon from -60 Latitude to -85 Latitude:

```
// Ideal Polygon
POLYGON ((-180 -85, 180 -85, 180 -60, -180 -60, -180 -85))
```

In javascript, the array of points on the outer ring is as follows:

```
var points180 = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-60, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-60, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -180)
];
```

When presented with this polygon, Google Maps renders a zero-width rectangle on ±180 Longitude instead of the expected block. See http://jsfiddle.net/StephenM/489aveLr/3/

If you add redundant, intermediate points along the edges of the polygon, Google maps will render it correctly. The following polygon works:

```
var points = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-72.5, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-60, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-60, 90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-60, 0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-60, -90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-60, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-72.5, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -180)
];
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/StephenM/489aveLr/4/

When working with trivial, hand-crafted polygon such as this, adding the intermediate points is easy and not really a problem, even if it shouldn't be necessary in my opinion.

Unfortunately, real-world scenarios are less simple.

I have found polygons in real-world data sources that are a bit like the second of the above examples but with the intermediate points on only one edge. Something like this:

```
var points = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-60, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-60, 90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-60, 0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-60, -90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-60, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -180)
];
```

Google Maps fails once again to render this and renders the inverse. See: http://jsfiddle.net/StephenM/489aveLr/5/

Clearly, Google Maps cares not a jot that these are counter-clockwise oriented rings and does whatever it pleases.

In the real-world case, when polygons are not hand-crafted, is there some way to modify them to make them render correctly or to configure Google Maps to heed the winding or orientation?

So far, the best idea I have is to add redundant intermediate points to edges that exceed some threshold length.

**UPDATE: OpenLayers v.3 Renders the Polygon Correctly**

It appears that migrating to OpenLayers v.3 is one way to resolve the issue. It renders the polygon perfectly, even in its most simplified (four vertex) form. See http://jsfiddle.net/StephenM/489aveLr/6/

The polygon object is defined as follows:

```
var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([[
    ol.proj.transform([-180, -85], sourceProjection, viewProjection),
    ol.proj.transform([180, -85], sourceProjection, viewProjection),
    ol.proj.transform([180, -60], sourceProjection, viewProjection),
    ol.proj.transform([-180, -60], sourceProjection, viewProjection),
    ol.proj.transform([-180, -85], sourceProjection, viewProjection),
]]);
```

(Repetition of the starting vertex is unnecessary under OpenLayers.)

Comment: You can try adding degrees, minutes, and seconds for your coordinates so it will be more exact.

Comment: I am super frustrated by this as well. Did you find any solution for google maps?

Comment: No. I switched to OpenLayers... which is rather shoddy but better than Google Maps.